# How to show unexpandable nodes in Powerbuilder Tree Datawindow

Tags: tree, powerbuilder, datawindow

I am using a tree datawindow in powerbuilder. This repesents a mixture of tree and table.

My problem is: the tree doesn't visibly distinguish between expandable und non-expandable nodes. If a node is not expandable, the icon in front of the node is still a plus sign, and if I click on the plus sign, the tree shows an empty node below the current node.

How can get the standard behaviour (node is not expandable, no icon or minus sign in front of the node)? Do I need to change the Data Set or is that a property of the tree that I can set?

The alternative woud be to use a native tree view, but that is less elegant than a tree data window in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the TreeView Datawindow. There is an expectation that data exists at all defined levels. There is no way to show that a node has no children. As inelegant as it may seem, the traditional treeview is the only way to go to get this level of control.

Comment: Ok, so it's back to the drawing board.